# PowerShell foreach file in folder using a lot of memory

Tags: memory, powershell, foreach

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and programming, so I'm sure this code can be optimized even more.

However, my biggest problem with this code is that it puts it's data from the foreach loop in memory. What is the best way to prevent this?

I started up rewriting this script from a script that I found here: [PowerShell: delete files older than x days](http://www.networknet.nl/apps/wp/published/powershell-delete-files-older-than-x-days)

Edit: Oh, there is about 60 000~ files in each TargetFolder by the way.

```
## Set Window Title
$title = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle
$titdef = $title
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Checking files. Do NOT close " + "($title)"

## Debug (0=Nothing, 1=Extended log, 2=Extended log+Screen)
$Debug = "2"

## Log file
$log = "C:\status\status.txt"
Add-Content $log "nul"

## Clear log before adding new data 
Remove-Item $log

## Folders to check
$TargetFolder1 = “\\server\c$\BiztalkProjects\UDC\output\ume”
$TargetFolder2 = “\\server\c$\BiztalkProjects\UDC\output\upp”

## Required stuff
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = “2”
$TwoDays = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$Folder1 = get-childitem $TargetFolder1 -include *
$Folder2 = get-childitem $TargetFolder2 -include *

## Window Message
"Checking for files newer than $Days days in:"
"$TargetFolder1"
"$TargetFolder2"
""
"This may take 5-15 minutes . . . (Will commit about 250MB~ RAM during the period)"

## Reset variable $OK to "0"
$OK = 0

if ($Debug -eq "2") {"Check1"}
foreach ($File in $Folder1) {
    $FileLastWrite = $File.LastWriteTime
    if ($File.LastWriteTime -le $TwoDays) {
        $OK = $OK + "0"
        if ($Debug -eq "2") {
            "OK + 0 (=$OK) $File ($FileLastWrite)"
            }
    } else {
        $OK = $OK + "1"
        if ($Debug -eq "2") {
            "OK + 1 (=$OK) $File ($FileLastWrite)" 
            }
    }
}
if ($Debug -eq "2") {"Check2"}
foreach ($File in $Folder2) {
    $FileLastWrite = $File.LastWriteTime
    if ($File.LastWriteTime -le $TwoDays) {
        $OK = $OK + "0"
        if ($Debug -eq "2") {
            "OK + 0 (=$OK) $File ($FileLastWrite)"
            }
    } else {
        $OK = $OK + "1"
        if ($Debug -eq "2") {
            "OK + 1 (=$OK) $File ($FileLastWrite)" 
            }
    }
}
if ($OK -gt "0") {
    if ($Debug -eq "2") {
        ""
        "Found $OK file(s) newer than $Days days"
        }
    Add-Content $log "OK"
    if ($Debug -ge "1") {
        Add-Content $log "Found $OK file(s) newer than $Days days"
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($Debug -eq "2") {
        ""
        "Found $OK file(s) newer than $Days days"
        }
    Add-Content $log "Error"
    if ($Debug -ge "1") {
        Add-Content $log "Found $OK file(s) newer than $Days days"
        }
    }
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $titdef
```

This version works. Thanks to all who helped!

```
## Set Window Title
$title = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle
$titdef = $title
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Checking files. Do NOT close " + "($title)"

## Debug (0=Nothing, 1=Extended log, 2=Extended log+Screen)
$Debug = "2"

## Log file
$log = "C:\status\status.txt"
Add-Content $log "nul"

## Clear log before adding new data 
Remove-Item $log

## Folders to check
$TargetFolder1 = “\\server\c$\BiztalkProjects\UDC\output\ume”
$TargetFolder2 = “\\server\c$\BiztalkProjects\UDC\output\upp”

## Required stuff
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = “2”
$TwoDays = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)

## Window Message
"Checking for files newer than $Days days in:"
"$TargetFolder1"
"$TargetFolder2"
""
"This may take 5-15 minutes . . ."

## Reset variable $OK to "0"
$OK = 0

get-childitem $TargetFolder1,$TargetFolder2 -filter *.xml |where-object {
    $FileLastWrite = $_.LastWriteTime
    if ($FileLastWrite -le $TwoDays) {
        $OK = $OK + "0"
    } else {
        $OK = $OK + "1"
    }
}
if ($OK -gt "0") {
    if ($Debug -eq "2") {
        ""
        "Found $OK file(s) newer than $Days days"
        }
    Add-Content $log "OK"
    if ($Debug -ge "1") {
        Add-Content $log "Found $OK file(s) newer than $Days days"
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($Debug -eq "2") {
        ""
        "Found $OK file(s) newer than $Days days"
        }
    Add-Content $log "Error"
    if ($Debug -ge "1") {
        Add-Content $log "Found $OK file(s) newer than $Days days"
        }
    }
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $titdef
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$Folder1 = get-childitem $TargetFolder1 -filter *.xml
```

Much more performant than using `include` (on a large set of files). Or even better:

```
get-childitem $TargetFolder1 -filter *.xml | % {}
```

---

**EDIT**

I see now, your problems are due to `include`! If you need to use wildcards and nor regular expressions to get the child item, use `filter` instead. Is much more performant because does not use regular expression matching.

Try:

```
$Folder1 = get-childitem $TargetFolder1 -filter *
```

even if it's not very clear what you are filtering there (or you want include)...everything? May be you don't need the wildcard at all.

---

In my humble opinion, the best way to prevent *foreach loop in memory* is *piping*. However, due to the nature of your script (many nested controls inside the loop) it's not that easy.

Try with:

```
$Folder1 | % {
  # ...
}
```

even if I doubt it will improve performances.

---

or:

```
get-childitem $TargetFolder1 -include * | % {
  # ...
}
```

Comment: A good refactoring (using function, better log system...) should make it a lot easier

Comment: Do you mean I should replace my foreach loop with your later suggestion? Wont that also loop through all files, and first when it ends it will clear up memory?

Comment: I'm trying to find if there are newer files than 2 days. If not, the application that puts files there have crashed. They are XML files. So this might be the way to do it?

    get-childitem $TargetFolder2 -filter *.xml

Comment: I replaced the foreach loops with $FolderX | % {} and the -include with -filter. Its still using 200MB+ and still takes forever to complete. (10 min~)

Comment: Try `get-childitem $TargetFolder1 -filter *.xml | % {` otherwise you really need to refactor your code as @Cedric suggests.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question to include the script that works. Take a look! (Out of topic: can I silent `get-childitem` to not output to screen?)

Comment: Strange! It shouldn't, you are printing information. You can try `> $null` at the end but it will shutup all your messages

Comment: Try `get-childitem ... | where-object {...} | Out-Null`

Comment: @empo I found I had a bug in my local version but not here on the website. Its solved and its working perfectly - just a bit slow.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
 $TS=(Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
 $COUNT = (get-childitem -recurse path1,path2 |where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $TS}|measure-object).Count
 if ($COUNT > 0) { Echo "There are $COUNT files" }
```

might be better (I haven't tested it for performance)

Comment: Thanks, that seems better optimized. But I'm not trying to delete files :) I'm only trying to get info if there are newer files than 2 days, if there isn't I'm gonna be notified by email or whatever.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw you mentioned deleting files and didn't check properly that was what you wanted! Anyway you are happy with empo's answer now.

Comment: Now updated code to just count the matching files and test the answer.

Comment: Your version is very stripped - I like it. Though it's hard to accept answers from two :-\